# Is there a point on the secp256k1 curve for any given X coordinate?

Tags: cryptography, secp256k1

There function in libsecp256k1 that allows you to directly set the field element to 32 bytes of your choice. Does secp256k1 *always* return a valid group element for any 32 byte value?

> secp256k1_fe_set_b32(&xpoint, bytes)
>
> secp256k1_ge_set_xo_var(ge, &xpoint, 0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of secp256k1's coordinate field is 2<sup>256</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> - 977.

That means there are only 2<sup>32</sup> + 977 (about 4 billion) possible 32-byte combinations that are not a valid coordinate.

Only slightly less than half (around 2<sup>255</sup> - 1.17 * 2<sup>127</sup>) of those are the X coordinate of a point on the curve (in fact, for every valid X coordinate, there are either exactly 0 or exactly 2 points on the curve).

Comment: Could you elaborate how you arrived at "around 2^255 - 1.17 * 2^127"?

Comment: I divided the curve order by two. You can find the curve order in the secp256k1 specification, or you can compute it using mathematical software like Sage.

Comment: FWIW, that order (=equal to the number of points on the curve, including infinity) is 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337.